# What is the best practice when creating boolean columns in Oracle?

Tags: oracle, datatypes

I faced again the serious problem, that Oracle simply doesn't have a boolean column type. I need to use `char(1)`, or `smallint`, or some other.

What is the best practice, how to emulate boolean values in Oracle?

(Space consumption isn't important now - but a good cooperation with java/hibernate line were important).

Comment: Why do you think not having the boolean data type is a _serious_ problem?

Comment: @mustaccio It is (was) easy to solve, what I consider serious is that Oracle can't support it.

Comment: @mustaccio Sorry for the late answer. But I consider this as a serious problem, because everybody uses _nonstandard_ ways to emulate boolean with SMALLINT or with CHAR(1). And these solutions are incompatible to eachother, so if you see a _big_ data structure and see a CHAR field, you won't know on the spot if it is really boolean or not. Another problem: comparing different field types would be ((BOOLFIELD1 = 'Y') AND (BOOLFIELD2 = 1)) OR ((BOOLFIELD1 = 'N') AND (BOOLFIELD2 = 0)) which is a terrible mess compared to BOOLFIELD1 = BOOLFIELD2.

Comment: @mustaccio There is another problem with booleans: having 1e+15 booleans would be most easily used in a bitfield and it is a very important thing, how is it actually physicall stored on the disk. If there isn't boolean in a db, then there is surely absolutely no possibility to optimize this out on the db-provided ways (f.e., with bitfields).

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2426145/oracles-lack-of-a-bit-datatype-for-table-columns

Comment: @RDFozz The posts are for the eternity, more exactly the continuously growing knowledge base is what attracts here more and more visitors. Rejecting an edit only because it happened to an old post, I think it only shows, 1) you simply won't understand how this whole SE works 2) you somehow becomes annoyed seeing that others get +2 reputation. | The grammar fix to my post is fine, and I am thankful to all of the parttakers (MDCCL and Codeflava). Furthermore, I consider it as a big honor as a native speaker fixes what I can't do.

Comment: @mustaccio - a seriously problematic aspect is that there is no programmatically reliable way for a calling program to generically identify booleans in a returned cursor as one is able to for a distinct type eg. date (type 12). The only option for intelligent caller handling of boolean values is to rely on naming standards being 100% reliable ...a super risky exercise.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I recommend you use a SMALLINT column with a default value required
(1=true, 0=false, default value = 0)

Comment: According to http://psoug.org/definition/SMALLINT.htm and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24240087/oracle-numberp-storage-size both `SMALLINT` and `INTEGER` would be stored as `NUMBER(38)` and take 2 bytes of space when holding just zeroes and ones. Same as `NUMBER(1)`, though.

Comment: I am using Oracle 12c standard. `SMALLINT` become to `NUMBER(38,0)` . I don't think use `SMALLINT` for boolean is best practice.

Answer (score 10):

I usually use a `number(1)` type combined with a check constraint:

```
some_flag number(1) not null check (some_flag in (1,0))
```

To make things crystal clear I also add a comment to that table:

```
comment on column some_table.some_flag is '0 is false, 1 is true';
```

so that the explanation on what "true" means can be seen when looking at the definition of the table.

I would avoid a character representation due to localization problems. But if you do, make sure you create the approriate check constraint. Because it's not clear if a `char(1)` would use `T`, `Y`, `y`, `t` (or even `W` or `J` which I have seen in German).

Comment: `W` and `J` woulnd't make any sense in German. More like `W` and `U`

Comment: @sschrass: all examples given, are for the "true" value.

Comment: Oh I see, my bad!